# Draw random numbers from a custom probability density function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, probability, probability-density, probability-theory

I want to sample `R` random numbers from a custom probability density function in Matlab.

This is the expression of the probability density function evaluated at `x`.

[image]

I thought about using `slicesample`

```
R=10^6;
f =  @(x) 1/(2*pi^(1/2))*(1/(x^(3/2)))*exp(-1/(4*x));
epsilon= slicesample(0.3,R,'pdf',f,'thin',1,'burnin',1000);
```

However, it does not work because I get the error

```
Error using slicesample (line 175)
The step-out procedure failed.
```

I tried to change starting value and values of `thin` and `burning` parameters but it does not seem to work. Could you advise, either on how to make `slicesample` work or on alternative solutions to sample random numbers from a custom probability density function in Matlab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let **X** be a random variable distributed according to your target pdf. Applying the change of variable *y* = 1/*x* and using the [well-known theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables) for a function of a random variable, the distribution of **Y** = 1/**X** is recognized to be a [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Characterization_using_shape_%CE%B1_and_rate_%CE%B2) with parameters *α* = 1/2, *β* = 1/4.

Therefore, it suffices to generate a Gamma random variable (using [`gamrnd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gamrnd.html)) with those parameters and take the inverse. Note that Matlab's definition of the Gamma distribution uses parameters *A* = *α*, *B* = 1/*β*.

```
R = 1e5; % desired sample size
x = 1./gamrnd(1/2, 4, [1 R]); % result
```

Check:

```
histogram(x, 'Normalization', 'pdf', 'BinEdges', 0:.1:10)
hold on
f = @(x) 1/2/sqrt(pi)./x.^(3/2).*exp(-1/4./x); % target pdf
fplot(f, 'linewidth', .75)
```

[image]